# What are some best papers on gradient descent for NN implementation?

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement GD for standard task of NN training :) The best papers for practioneer I've founded so far are:

1) "Efficient BackProp" by Yann LeCun et al.

2) "Stochastic Gradient Descent Tricks" by Leon Bottou

Are there some other must read papers on this topic?

Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking for online resources are generally discouraged. This might be more useful if you state what aspects you want more insight on, and see if people can write up those insights possibly with links to papers.

Comment: It's not what you are asking. But you can take a look at this link of [Data Science](http://subasish.github.io/pages/data_sc_best_papers/) best papers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general request for off-site resources, with no problem statement or other way to scope recommendations.